# How to use Twitter bootstrap modules in a Marionette JS app

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, marionette

I am building a Backbone.Marionette webapp.
I am using Twitter Bootstrap for the UI elements.

I would like to use the tooltip module in one of my views.

**The template**

```
<a href="#" class="hepsock" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">Tooltip</a>
```

**The View**

```
class List.User extends App.Views.ItemView
 template: "users/list/templates/_user"
 tagName: "div"
 className: "item"

 onBeforeRender:
  $('a').tooltip()
```

When using this setup tooltip is not activated/not working but I get no errors.

*If I however include this code directly into the template file I get tooltips working.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

How can I call/activate bootstrap modules in views?

Thankful for all input!

Comment: Shoulnd't you use the `onRender`? e.g  `onRender:
  $el.tooltip()`

Comment: Did not work. Got this: Uncaught ReferenceError: $el is not defined

Comment: What about `$(el).tooltip()`?

Comment: `this.$el.find('a').tooltip()` or `this.$('a').tooltip()`. And you may want to do that in onRender, not beforeRender. Your $el doesn't exist yet in onBeforeRender

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#beforerender--onbeforerender-event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@bryanbuchs is correct.  Here is a working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/L6nzS/

```
var ToolView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template:"#tool-template",
    tagName: "span",
    onRender: function() {
        this.$el.find('a').tooltip();
    }
});
```

Comment: I probably should have posted that as an answer, not a comment. Thanks, Scott.

Comment: No worries, I already wrote the fiddle by the time I saw your comment.  Seemed a shame to let it go to waste.

Comment: Perfect! It works fine. Is this the best way to instantiate plugins?